# How to do something indefinitely until a condition is met, with no loop?

Tags: javascript

Whenever I use a loop, the tab crashes. I can't seem to figure out how to work this out. I just start typing `while(true) {document.getElementById("loadingText").textContent++;}` and before I can type `if(document.getElementById("loadingText").textContent === "100") {break;}` the screen freezes and the tab crashes. Can someone help me?

Comment: Could you post the code you used? There are methods of doing this without traditional loops, but the browser souldn't crash with a simple loop like this.

Comment: I would not think that a for loop for this should crash the browser. Can you share with us the code that crashes the tab?

Comment: "Do something indefinitely until a condition is met" is pretty much the definition of what a loop does, provided that the body of the loop actually does things to change the controlling condition. If not, then what you want is some kind of event handler.

Comment: Sure. I just start typing `while(true) {document.getElementById("loadingText").textContent++;}` and before I can type `if(document.getElementById("loadingText").textContent === "100") {break;}` the screen freezes and the tab crashes.

Comment: @brandon, please update (edit) your answer and put the code sample there

Comment: Have a look at a for loop and see if that makes the difference, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration

Comment: What's the point of looping? Can't you just hardcode the final value? If you want actually to see the text changing, a loop is not suitable, there's no time for a browser to render a new value, until the loop has end. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearTimeout

Comment: It sounds like you're using a online editor that refreshes the browser window with each code change in the editor.

Comment: @Andy Yes that is true.

Comment: @Brandon don't close the curly brace until you've added the conditional. Note that as others have said you can't use the `++` on text that way.

Comment: Your `while` has no condition that is met to stop the loop; that's why it hangs. If you can, turn off the real-time update until you're happy with the code, _then_ run it. For example `while (i <= 100) { // stuff }`  - making sure you define `i` then increment it in the statement.

Comment: @andy I'm on KhanAcademy, I can't turn it off.

Comment: In addition to incrementing, you may also want to add a wait time by using a setTimeout function. By simply evaluating a loop like this, you're basically pushing to do it as fast as possible which can be very taxing depending on the environment. You need to have some condition, as mentioned above, and should add some time to pause between increments.

Comment: OK, just change it to anything except `true`. It'll error instead of going mental, and give you the opportunit to amend it.

Comment: You are asking if your property is === "100" as ++ increment the numeric value, the loop never breaks, compare to 100 instead of "100" as string

Comment: @Andy Thanks! You fixed it!

Comment: @Brandon You should really rewrite your question. It has nothing to do with loops not working, causing browser crashes, avoiding iterations, etc. It's really *"KhanAcademy automatically executes my code as I'm writing it. How can I stop it from choking before I'm finished writing a `while` loop?"*. This is a great example of an **XY Problem**.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using an online editor with real-time browser updates based on changes, you need to make sure you don't make your code loop infinitely. Sadly that's what `while (true) { // code }` does if there's no code in the statement to break the loop.

For the timebeing, until you've figured out the meat of that loop, just intentionally cause an error:

```
while (i <= 100) { // code }
```

which you can go ahead an amend until you get the desired result.

There are a couple of things you should take into account.

1) You should cache the element once so you're not repeatedly grabbing it on each loop iteration.

2) `textContent` is a string, so you can't use `el.textContent++` as it won't be successfully evaluated.

3) You'll find it difficult to slow a traditional loop down so that you can see the number increment properly.

So here's a method using `setTimeout` instead of a traditional loop.

```js
// Cache the element
const el = document.getElementById("loadingText");

(function displayNumber(n, end) {

  // Repeat until the iteration number (n)
  // is 10 (for this example)
  if (n <= end) {
    el.textContent = n;

    // Wait 0.5s then call the function again with an increased n
    setTimeout(() => displayNumber(++n, end), 500);
  }

// Pass in the initial number, and the end limit
}(1, 10));
```

```html
<div id="loadingText"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that a textContent could be incremented. Try Node.value++.
If this still doesn't works. To run an infinite loop you can use setInterval(); method. 
example:

```
var i=0;
var z = setInterval(foo,10);
function foo() { alert(i); }
```

In the above example the function foo() will execute infintely with a gap of 10 mili seconds. You can put it to 0 ms as well if you wish to.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking if your property is === "100" as ++ increment the numeric value, the loop never breaks, compare to 100 instead of "100" as string

```
if(document.getElementById("loadingText").textContent == "100") {break;}
```

or

```
if(document.getElementById("loadingText").textContent === 100) {break;}
```